# Pressure testing watch using common tools?

Tags: pressure

I want to test if my new watch complies with ISO 2281 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_Resistant_mark) That seems doable in the kitchen apart from 2 steps:

- Resistance to water overpressure. Immersion of the watch in a suitable pressure vessel and subjecting it within 1 minute to the rated pressure for 10 minutes, or to 2 bar in case where no additional indication is given. Then the overpressure is reduced to the ambient pressure within 1 minute. No evidence of water intrusion or condensation is allowed.
- Resistance to air overpressure. Exposing the watch to an overpressure of 2 bar. The watch shall show no air-flow exceeding 50 μg/min.

My watch is rated for 10atm. Any ideas on how to test those using common tools (i.e. no access to lab equipment)?